# In chkdsk, does /b imply /f?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd.exe, chkdsk

*This is one of those small everyday things that I've always wondered but have always considered too trivial to ask. I decided to in the end because it's interesting to know and would save me a few keystrokes. Apologies in advance if it appears common sense to some, I just wanted to confirm.*

The help for CMD's `chkdsk` lists three switches that imply others:

> **/F** Fixes errors on the disk
>
> **/R** Locates bad sectors and recovers readable information (implies /F)
>
> **/B** NTFS only: Re-evaluates bad clusters on the volume (implies /R)
>
> **/X** Forces the volume to dismount first if necessary. All opened handles to the volume would then be invalid (implies /F).

I know from the final one that `/x` implies `/f`, so if I specify `/x` I don't need to also specify `/f`.

However, if `/b` implies `/r` and `/r` implies `/f`, does `/b` also imply `/f`? In other words, if I wanted to run `chkdsk` with all of the above switches (plus the `/v` for verbose output), would I need to run:

```
chkdsk PATH /r /b /x /v
```

...or would `chkdsk PATH /b /x /v` be sufficient?

Comment: Why would one "higher level" (/B) implication eradicate one at a lower level (/F)?

Comment: I'm not sure @Hannu, but I know that tech isn't always intuitive, and therefore saw no reason not to confirm that it works the way I've always expected it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chkdsk PATH /b /x /v` should be sufficient, /f and /r will be inherited.